# Meteor template gets created twice, after adding accounts-ui package

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts, accounts

I started to learn meteor and i did setup a small test project. I made a simple template like so test.html:

```
<head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>

 {{> TestPage}}

</body>
<template name="TestPage">
    <p>hello</p>
</template>
```

I also installed `iron-router` and i tried did setup the routes. Then i checked with `meteor run`, and everything was ok, i got a plain page with one `hello` text sign. After that i wanted to try and make simple login page, i added `meteor add accounts-ui accounts-password`. After that, when i tried to load my page, the `hello` displayed twice. So i went to the js part to try and  understand what is going on. Here is full test.js:

```
var textMessage = "";
var textMessageDep = new Deps.Dependency;

var getTextMessage = function()
{
    textMessageDep.depend();
    return textMessage;
};
var setTextMessage = function (newValue) {
    if (newValue !== textMessage)
        textMessageDep.changed();
    textMessage = newValue;
};
Template.TestPage.onRendered(function () {
   console.log('on rendered');
});
Template.TestPage.onCreated(function () {
    console.log('on created');
});
```

So from that, i managed to get the following output in js console:

```
on created
on created
on rendered
```

`On created` event is called two times for some reason, that's why i get two copies of template rendered. How to correctly overcome this issue? I assume meteor waits for `Meteor.Users` collection to get ready? I didn't even add any users to this collection.

Also this is how my router config looks like:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('/', {
        onBeforeAction: function () {
        // here planned to add 
        // if(!Meteor.user()) {}
        // 
               this.render('TestPage'); 
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you asked Meteor to render the template twice. By default, `meteor` will load any file with the `body` tag first, which is the one you put `TestPage` template at this moment. Then you put into the `onBeforeAction` another rendering for the `TestPage`, therefore, another `TestPage` appears on page. One way to solve this is removing the one in the `onBeforeAction`

The correct way specify the template to render in the router is

```
this.route('TestPage', {
    path: '/'
});
```

and remove the one in the `body`